# How to get server certificate chain then verify it's valid and trusted in Java

Tags: java, x509certificate

I need to create an Https connection with a remote server then retrieve and verify the certificate.

I have established the connection fine:

```
try {  
    url = new URL(this.SERVER_URL);  
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   
    HttpsURLConnection secured = (HttpsURLConnection) con;  
    secured.connect(); 
}
```

But it seems `getServerCertificateChain()` method is undefined by the type `HttpsURLConnection`.

So how do I retrieve the server certificate chain? My understanding is that `getServerCertificateChain()` should return an array of `X509Certificate` objects and that this class has methods I can use to interrogate the certificate.

I need to verify that:

1. the certificate is valid and trusted,
2. check the Certificate Revocation List Distribution Point against the certificate serial number
3. make sure it isn't expired and
4. check that the URL in the certificate is matches another (which I already have retrieved ).

I'm lost and would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you sure that Java's https client code doesn't already do all four things for you?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this ? Whether Certificate is trusted or not ? Any Solution for that

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The method you want is [getServerCertificates](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#getServerCertificates%28%29), not `getServerCertificateChain`. There is some nice sample code [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-https-client-httpsurlconnection-example/).

---

***EDIT***

Added some sample code of my own. Good starting point for you. Don't forget to look at the Javadocs for [HttpsURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) and [X509Certificate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html).

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class TestSecuredConnection {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestSecuredConnection tester = new TestSecuredConnection();
        try {
            tester.testConnectionTo("https://www.google.com");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public TestSecuredConnection() {
        super();
    }

    public void testConnectionTo(String aURL) throws Exception {
        URL destinationURL = new URL(aURL);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) destinationURL
                .openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        Certificate[] certs = conn.getServerCertificates();
        for (Certificate cert : certs) {
            System.out.println("Certificate is: " + cert);
            if(cert instanceof X509Certificate) {
                try {
                    ( (X509Certificate) cert).checkValidity();
                    System.out.println("Certificate is active for current date");
                } catch(CertificateExpiredException cee) {
                    System.out.println("Certificate is expired");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you -- I am coding to spec from a large corporations manual and I was beginning to suspect that whoever wrote this section had erred.  I'm a neophyte though when it comes to java networking so I've been spending hours trying to figure what the hell the difference is between getServerCertificateChain and getServerCertificates.

Comment: How do I interrogate the certificates though as per the four requirements I listed above?

Comment: You will have to convert the certificates to X509Certificates and use the methods on that class.

Comment: How do I retrieve the url in the certificate?  How do I check if it is valid and trusted and not expired?  I am a networking neophyte and I'm finding most resources on the net only add to my confusion.

Comment: Did you look at the Javadocs for X509Certificate? It has a lot of the methods you are looking for. You're going to have to do some reading, also look at addition to my answer above.

Comment: I am confused though because X509Certificate is an abstract class and some it's methods like checkValidity() are as well.  I am looking at X509TrustManager as well and there is a method, checkClientTrusted but I run into the same question with that interface as well.  Is there a tutorial or any articles you can recommend to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Wow.. somehow I didn't see the sample code you wrote when I made that comment.  Guess I need to catch up on my sleep :)  Thanks!!!

Comment: That was extremely helpful - all I need to do now is figure out how to extract the url from the certificate.

Comment: **Warning**: the code above does **not** fully validate the chain, it only checks if the certificate is within its validity period.

Comment: This code only lets you examine the certificates if they are accepted. The call to getServerCertificates will return null if the certs are not trusted.

Answer (score 2):

Quick googling brought me to this example using BouncyCastle. I think it better answers the question.
http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/12/01/x509-certificate-validation-in-java-build-and-verify-chain-and-verify-clr-with-bouncy-castle/

Comment: code not formatted properly in that blog.. Here is the source code https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/tags/cxf-2.4.1/distribution/src/main/release/samples/sts_issue_operation/src/main/java/demo/sts/provider/cert/

Answer (score 1):

This sample code mentioned by Kirby and arulraj.net has been removed from Apache CXF in 2011 and did not support OCSP. The [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) project "resurrected" this code and added OCSP support and more features that were missing in the original code, e.g. CRL signature check. Since release 2.0.13 the improved source code is available in the examples subproject, in the CertificateVerifier class. It is also [available online](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/cert/CertificateVerifier.java?view=markup) with small improvements.

The code is not claiming to be perfect, and does not yet check whether the root is trusted. Development is tracked in JIRA issue [PDFBOX-3017](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3017).