# How to verify a SSL java certificate

Tags: java, certificate

I was wondering if there is any way to verify that importing a SSL certificate in a java application has been successful via running the application?

I have verified the certificate files etc, but I want to double check the application.

Comment: what kind of certificate?

Comment: Be more specific about your problem. Read carefully: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page before you post your question

Comment: Sorry. The question has been updated.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199129/how-to-get-server-certificate-chain-then-verify-its-valid-and-trusted-in-java)

Comment: What is a problem?
What did you do?What didn't work?
Please explain all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once opening the java application, there was an information icon. Pressing this shows the specifications of the certificates.