# Query a server's certificates with BouncyCastle

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle

I'm writing a java application that allows the user to enter a URL and get the info of all the server's certificates. In OpenSSL, I would use:

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect [server] -servername [server] </dev/null`

But how do I simulate this with the BouncyCastle library? I've been googling and not coming up with anything at all, so I know I'm either using the wrong search terms (not a security expert at all) or this can't be done programmatically? TIA.

Comment: There no reason to use Bouncycastle, it's not magical despite its name. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7199129/238704) and the answers.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Excellent, thank you!